# Actual failure message in the transaction controller if it consist of multiple sampler

Tags: jmeter

Would like to print the exact message in the transaction controller if it have multiple child sampler. In my test plan there are multiple transaction controller and each transaction have multiple sampler inside it. An i Have selected "generate parent sample".

No during my load execution sometime few controller fails, and they only give me message like "Number of samples in transaction : 3, number of failing samples : 1" in the controller.

How to print the exact sampler name with the failure message in the parent controller ?

Please refer the image attached.
[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is not possible as of [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html)
2. I don't think you really need this because the information in any case is being stored in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles):

   [image]

   and given it's in the .jtl results file you can also see this at the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html):

   [image]

Running your test in GUI mode and [especially having View Results Tree listener enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/) violates [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)